# вывод данных из бд в меню и подгрузка дополнительных selects

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, css

На экран выводится 3 селектора , значения в которые должны подгружаться из БД, в зависимости от заполнения. Например: в select1 выбрана страна Россия, в select2 передаются города России, после выбора города, в select3 предаются районы города и т.д. Максимальное значение выводимых на экран селектов 5. Сразу на экране должно быть 3. 4 и select5 должны выводиться по необходимости(если цепочка длиннее чем страна-город-район) с помощью jquery. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, с чего мне начать, и как продолжить реализацию такого меню:) Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Никакого кода не приведено, поэтому приведу один из возможных алгоритмов:

Смотрим `select1` - если пуст, то отправляем на рендер.
Если не пуст, отправляем запрос к БД и вытаскиваем города, помещаем их в `select2` и отправляем на рендер.
Если и `select2` не пуст, запрашиваем районы города нужной страны, помещаем в `select3` и отправляем на рендер.
Повторить сколько нужно раз.